# Using AoT pre-compiled component factories for JiT compilation

Tags: angular, angular-aot, angular-compiler

I have a random markups from back-end that should be compiled in runtime with JiT. Every component used in this markups is already pre-compiled with AoT (added to entryComponents block) and so has component factory in runtime. When JiT compiles provided markup it ignores existing components factories and re-compile every inner component.
Is there any way to provide component's AoT pre-compiled factories to JiT compilator to compile only one dynamic component with dynamic template?

Markup that should be compilated looks like this

```
<exercise1 smth="smth">
  <exercise1-answer>smth</exercise1-answer>
</exercise1>
<some-wrapper-cmp>
  <exercise2 smth="smth">
    <exercise2-answer>smth</exercise2-answer>
  </exercise2>
</some-wrapper-cmp>
```

with arbitrary nesting (regular markup can contains 1500-2000 DOM nodes)

p.s. i'm using this way to get JiT with AoT https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15510#issuecomment-294301758 and then just

```
const component = Component({ template })(class {});
const module = NgModule({ imports, declarations: [ component ], schemas })(class {});

this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module)
  .then(factories => factories.componentFactories.filter(factory => factory.componentType === component)[0])
  .then(componentFactory => {
    this.componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(
      componentFactory,
      null,
      this.viewContainerRef.injector
    );

    this.compilationEnd.emit();
  });`enter code here`
```

Comment: Please add more specifix example. Maybe you can create github repository with your problem

Comment: what example do you mean? I've added a makrup example and comment about it.

Comment: Which components from markup have already precompiled factories? Which components are you adding to dynamic module? It would be better to understand if you provided a minimal reproduction

Comment: Every component from markup is precompiled, i only need to compile in runtime this template via dynamically created component (it's the one who should be compiled via JiT)

Comment: @drow Did you ever resolve your issue. I'm running into the same thing. Consuming AOT compiled components from dynamic JIT compiled components.

Comment: @adamclerk nope, we moved to manually instantiating each component on inserted in DOM markup via `componentFactory.create`
also there is some answer here but i did not try it https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19901